# How could I check the meaning of Vscode's popup-menu icon stands for?

Tags: visual-studio-code

For example,local variables have a kind of icon and function has another kind of icon.How could I check all the meanings of these icons stand for?

Comment: Do you mean the intellisense?

Comment: yes. There are different icons standing for functions,local variables,static members and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [vscode documentation on intellisense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense):

[image: VS code intellisense]